# Spinner onItemSelected do not called when selected item is it's hint

Tags: android, spinner, onitemclicklistener

I have a custom spinner.

@Override
    public void setOnItemSelectedListener(final OnItemSelectedListener listener) {

```
    final OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (hint != null || floatingLabelText != null) {
                if (!floatingLabelVisible && position != 0) {
                    showFloatingLabel();
                } else if (floatingLabelVisible && position == 0) {
                    hideFloatingLabel();
                }
            }

            if (position != lastPosition && error != null) {
                setError(null);
            }
            lastPosition = position;

            if (listener != null) {
                position = hint != null ? position - 1 : position;
                listener.onItemSelected(parent, view, position, id);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onNothingSelected(parent);
            }
        }
    };

    super.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener);
}
```

Spinner onItemSelected do not called when selected item is it's hint.
so when user select spinner hint onItemSelected do not called.

so how I can handle hint selection in spinner?

Comment: you can check position manually also

Comment: Please add code to get better explanation

Comment: @Chetna unfortunately on select a hint, onItemSelected do not called and I cannot get position.

Comment: please add your code

Comment: can you set item Selected Listener or not

Comment: `"so when user select spinner hint ..."` what spinner hint?

Comment: @Chetna  I updated the question with code. check it.

Comment: @pskink i mean spinner items title. when you put a hint for spinner, on click it it's hint come to head of items.

Comment: what do you mean by hint??spinner hint is itself an element of the adapter you use in your spinner

Comment: why do you override `setOnItemSelectedListener`? what parameter do you pass to that method? it seems you are not controlling your code...

Answer (score 0):

```
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "its your hint ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "do here what you want ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: here **sp** is your spinner object

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Spinner spinner_subcate = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.subcat_spin);
```

ArrayAdapter dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_item){

```
                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        if (position == getCount()) {
                            ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("");
                            ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setHint(getItem(getCount())); //"Hint to be displayed"
                        }

                        return v;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getCount() {
                        return super.getCount()-1; // you dont display last item. It is used as hint.
                    }

                };

                dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);

                dataAdapter1.add("list item1");
                dataAdapter1.add("list item2");
                dataAdapter1.add("list item3");
                dataAdapter1.add("hint");

                // Spinner click listener
                spinner_subcate.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        String sub_cat = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        Log.d("sub cat::",sub_cat);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });

                // attaching data adapter to spinner
                spinner_subcate.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
                spinner_subcate.setSelection(dataAdapter1.getCount()); //set the hint the default selection so it appears on launch.
```